# Install dotnet core on ec2 linux AMI 2 (c6g)

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, .net-core

I am trying to install dotnet-sdk-3.0 on linux AMI 2 ec2 instance (c6g). I am new to linux so tried couple of commands but nothing seems working for me. I tried below.

```
sudo rpm -Uvh https://packages.microsoft.com/config/centos/7/packages-microsoft-prod.rpm


sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-3.1
sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-3.0
```

When tried above i am getting below error.

```
[ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 console]$ sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-3.0
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                               | 3.7 kB     00:00
amzn2extra-docker                                        | 3.0 kB     00:00
amzn2extra-nginx1.12                                     | 1.3 kB     00:00
packages-microsoft-com-prod                              | 3.0 kB     00:00
packages-microsoft-com-prod/primary_db                     | 288 kB   00:00
No package dotnet-sdk-3.0 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Then i tried

```
mkdir -p "$HOME/dotnet" && tar zxf dotnet-sdk-3.0.100-linux-x64.tar.gz -C                                                                              "$HOME/dotnet"
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet
```

After this tried the dotnet command but got the error. dotnet: command not found

Finally tried below:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/dotnet && tar zxf dotnet-sdk-3.1.302-linux-arm64.tar.gz -C                                                                                         $HOME/dotnet
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet
dotnet
dotnet --list-sdk
```

when i run this, i got below error

```
[ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 home]$ dotnet --list-sdk
Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support.
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
   at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode.GetGlobalizationInvariantMode()
   at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode..cctor()
   at System.Globalization.CultureData.CreateCultureWithInvariantData()
   at System.Globalization.CultureData.get_Invariant()
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..cctor()
   at System.String.ToLowerInvariant()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.RuntimeEnvironment.GetArch()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.RuntimeEnvironment..cctor()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeIdentifier()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.MulticoreJitProfilePathCalculator.CalculateProfileRootPath()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.MulticoreJitActivator.StartCliProfileOptimization()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.MulticoreJitActivator.TryActivateMulticoreJit()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(System.String[])
Aborted
```

also tried to run the dotnet <dotnet-project.dll> and received this error.

```
Failed to load ▒r▒), error: /home/ec2-user/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.0.0/libhostpolicy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
An error occurred while loading required library libhostpolicy.so from [/home/ec2-user/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.0.0]
[ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 console]$
```

I have followed the microsoft document as well.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-centos

Nothing seems working for me. Can someone please help me here, i am stuck from last 2 days.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am completely newbie to linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running this on arm64/aarch64. It's a relatively new architecture. It's also incompatible with the Intel 64-bit architecture (`x86_64` or `x64`). So you need to watch out for that.

## Installing via RPM

Edit: So, this is just not going to work if you want to use RPM packages.

Quoting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-centos:

> Package manager installs are only supported on the x64 architecture. Other architectures, such as ARM, must manually install the .NET Core SDK or .NET Core Runtime. For more information, see the manually install section below.

You are using `aarch64`/`arm64`. You are not using `x64`, so this is not going to work.

You need to use the tarball installation method.

<s>Out of date suggestions:</s>

> I am trying to install dotnet-sdk-3.0 on linux AMI 2 ec2 instance (c6g).

> ```
> sudo rpm -Uvh https://packages.microsoft.com/config/centos/7/packages-microsoft-prod.rpm
> ```

You are running Amazon Linux 2, right? As the URL here says, this is for CentOS 7. It may (or it may not) work on your Linux distribution. Anyway, try it out.

> ```
> $ sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-3.0
> No package dotnet-sdk-3.0 available.
> Error: Nothing to do
> ```

The error says that it can't find this package. Maybe a package with this name doesn't exist? Maybe you are using the wrong name? Try using `yum list` to find the correct name:

```
sudo yum list 'dotnet-sdk*'
```

It should show you a list of packages, including names like `dotnet-sdk-3.0.103`. You can install that package by name, then:

```
sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-3.0.103
```

If that doesn't work, try another package name from `yum list` and try installing that.

## Installing manually

> Then i tried
>
> ```
> mkdir -p "$HOME/dotnet" && tar zxf dotnet-sdk-3.0.100-linux-x64.tar.gz -C "$HOME/dotnet"
> export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet
> export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet
> ```
>
> After this tried the `dotnet` command but got the error. dotnet: command not found

You are running an `aarch64` machine. You need to use the `arm64` tarball, not the `x64` tarball. The `x64` tarball is for an Intel processor. It will not work on an ARM processor.

<s>That's surprising. Let me break down what this set of steps is doing:</s>

1. `mkdir -p "$HOME/dotnet"` creates a directory named `dotnet` in your home directory
2. `tar xf ...` extracts the dotnet SDK tarball in the `dotnet` directory you created in step 1
3. `export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet` defines an environment variable `DOTNET_ROOT`. .NET Runtime needs it; I am a bit fuzzy myself on why
4. `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet` adds the directory you installed the .NET SDK into to the environment variable `PATH`. `PATH` is a list of locations that the OS uses to search for a command that you enter. For example, when you type `dotnet` in the command line it searches for `dotnet` executable (think `dotnet.exe` on Windows) in this list of directories.

So let's try and debug it one by one:

- Does the directory `dotnet` exist in your main home directory (aka `$HOME`)? Can you `cd ~/dotnet`? Does that work?
- After you extract the tarball, do you see a file named `dotnet` in the `dotnet` directory in your `$HOME`? Does `ls $HOME/dotnet/dotnet` work? What does it show you?
- What does `echo $PATH` show you? Does it include that dotnet directory in the value?
- If you run `which dotnet`, does it find the `dotnet` executable in your main `$HOME` directory?

## Running the SDK

> when i run this, i got below error

> ```
> [ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 home]$ dotnet --list-sdk
> Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support
> ```

The error includes this phrase: Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system.

It really means that. You need to install the ICU package for your Linux distribution:

```
sudo yum install libicu
```

And then try running `dotnet --list-sdk` again.

## Error Running `dll`

> ```
> Failed to load ▒r▒), error: /home/ec2-user/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.0.0/libhostpolicy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> An error occurred while loading required library libhostpolicy.so from [/home/ec2-user/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.0.0]
> ```

This is strange. It says it can't find a file that should be part of the .NET Core installation.

- What does `dotnet --list-runtimes` say? Does it show the 3.0.0 runtime installed? If not, that means your installation is messed up. You should probably install .NET Core 3.0 again. (Or better yet, install 3.1 because 3.0 has been end-of-life'd).
- Does the file `/home/ec2-user/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.0.0/libhostpolicy.so` exist? If it doesn't it's the same problem as above: your installation is messed up.
- What does `file /home/ec2-user/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.0.0/libhostpolicy.so` say? Is it an `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object`?

  - The output is: `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64`
  - This is a `x86-64` file! In other words, you have (somehow) installed an `linux-x64` (Intel 64-bit architecture) runtime. Not too surprisingly, it doens't work on the ARM 64 bit architecture. You need to delete this and re-install the SDK. I suggest just blowing away your current installation (`rm -rf $HOME/dotnet`) and install the `linux-arm64` SDK again.

Comment: `sudo yum list 'dotnet-sdk*'`
This gives me 
`[ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ sudo yum list 'dotnet-sdk*'
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Error: No matching Packages to list`

Comment: `Does the directory dotnet exist in your main home directory (aka $HOME)? Can you cd ~/dotnet? Does that work?`
Yes
`After you extract the tarball, do you see a file named dotnet in the dotnet directory in your $HOME? Does ls $HOME/dotnet/dotnet work? What does it show you?`
yes
`[ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ ls $HOME/dotnet/dotnet
/home/ec2-user/dotnet/dotnet`
`$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/home/ec2-user/dotnet:/home/ec2-user/dotnet`
`$ which dotnet
~/dotnet/dotnet`

Comment: When i ran command `sudo yum install libicu` I got a message `Package libicu-50.2-4.amzn2.aarch64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

Comment: Oh, is this an `aarch64` machine? I missed the `arm64` in the question. Everything makes more sense now. Going to edit my answer again.

Comment: `What does file /home/ec2-user/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.0.0/libhostpolicy.so say? Is it an ELF 64-bit LSB shared object?` - it says _ ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=36c3a75b75401675fa55296e845b5330e9041b05, stripped_

Comment: after blowing up current installation and installing again with linux-arm64, it works. I had to make one more change in runtimeconfig.json to add `"System.Globalization.Invariant": true` to make it to work

Comment: Thank you for your all the help and guidance, much Appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work on Amazon Linux 2 ARM64 with the following steps:

1. Download and build a recent version of International Components for Unicode. <del>Amazon Linux 2 has version 50 available in the package manager, but dotnet looks for version 55 or later. When Amazon Linux updates this, this step won't be necessary anymore and can be replaced with `sudo yum install icu`.
   Install gcc and python3 because they'll be needed for building `libicu`. It takes a few minutes to build the library.</del> Amazon Linux 2 recently added `libicu60` to the package manager, so you can simply install it with yum:

```
sudo yum -y install libicu60
```

2. Follow the instructions from Microsoft to install the dotnet sdk. Download the dotnet sdk from the Microsoft Website. You may need to download from [this link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1) to get the latest version, but the link below worked for me.

```
cd ~
wget https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/5ee48114-19bf-4a28-89b6-37cab15ec3f2/f5d1f54ca93ceb8be7d8e37029c8e0f2/dotnet-sdk-3.1.302-linux-arm64.tar.gz
mkdir -p $HOME/dotnet && tar zxf ~/dotnet-sdk-3.1.302-linux-arm64.tar.gz -C $HOME/dotnet
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet
```

3. Test that it's working

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-69-243 ~]$ dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.302 [/home/ec2-user/dotnet/sdk]
```